# Multiple call to startService()

Tags: android

If more calls to `startService()` are made simultaneously from various components how are they resolved? I mean the second call waits from the first call to finish executing `onStartCommand()`, the third for the second etc....or not?

I'm getting confused because of this declaration from the offical docs:

> However, because you handle each call to onStartCommand() yourself, **you can perform multiple requests simultaneously**.